# Cannot grant SUPER privilege to root in MySQL 5.7.36

Tags: mysql, database, privileges

I am trying to run the following command in MySQL as the root user:

`set global log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;`

However, this gives me the following error:

`Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation`

To overcome this, I tried to grant the SUPER privilege to the root user by running:

`GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO 'root'@'my-host' IDENTIFIED BY 'my-password';`

This in turn gives me the error:

`Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)`.

So I am not really sure what to do. The MySQL version is `5.7.36` and I am connecting to the database remotely. The root user is also set to `mysql_native_password` as well. Any ideas on what I can do?

Answer (score 2):

This database was part of Google Cloud SQL and with managed databases like this and Amazon RDS, SUPER privileges are not supported. To enable this parameter, you need to set it through the Google Cloud SQL flags or in case of Amazon RDS, the parameter group.